# "Share" popup is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, share-this

I'm on a roll... bugs just keep hunting me today!

Well, click "share" and see for yourself:

> [image]

The textbox with the share link we all used to know and copy is now missing and the poor "close" which is referring to the share popup is left without background and clicking it does nothing.

Browser: Chrome 30, stable build. Happens only here on Meta right now.

**Note**: the share links themselves (Google+, Facebook etc) are working, I'm referring to the functionality of the "share" itself, where we used to have textbox with the link selected by default:

> [image]

Comment: it seems that the pictures are not rendered?

Comment: Win 7 IE10 reproduced only on Meta

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ah, it's meta specific. Didn't see that at first. Yes, now I reproduced it (Chrome 30.0.1599.101 Win7)

Comment: Mr. O. Le - not going to fall for your booby trap so hope you're reading anyway. What pictures are not rendered?

Comment: The links are working for me, I just don't see the social network icons.

Comment: @Bill the main problem is the missing textbox, I always use it to copy short link instead of copying the whole URL. Updated to prevent further confusion. :)

Comment: @Doorknob Also reproduced, chrome same version.

Comment: Any one else tried to close the popup in the screenshot? :P

Comment: I have the same issue. No errors in js console, no 404.

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 24.0 on windows 7

Comment: So many bugs in a short time span [who do we blame today](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/).

Comment: @bluefeet I think we need a new wheel, that one won't stand the pressure for much longer! ;)

Comment: Anyone recommend a coffee substitute?

Comment: @Oded sleep. Lots of it. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Not in my house. Two young boys not conductive to lots of sleep.

Comment: @Oded recipe for sleep in your case: 2 iPad/iPhone or actually any interactive cellular smartphone device. Give each boy one device full with cool games. Let them play. Go to sleep. ;)

Comment: Will then be up awake waiting for social services to come knocking on the door ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order of precedence matters.

I got it wrong :(

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Looking forward for build 2013.10.22.1542 :)

Comment: No comment. Oh.

Comment: Well, you are fixing those bugs fast enough with or without coffee - so no harm done!